# ReactJS.NET : Unable to get click events to fire

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs.net

I'm running ReactJS.NET with ASP.NET MVC, and everything renders well, except... i cannot get any kind of events to fire...

**What i have tried :**

1) Eliminating all JQuery references/usages - *no success*

2) onHover, onClick, with functions both inside and outside of the React-component - *no success*

**Here is my code :**

Attaching ProductLine React component in index.cshtml

```
@Html.React("ProductLine", Model)
```

**React component**

```
function addToCart() {
alert("Hoohohoho!!!");
};

var ProductLine = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return(
            <div className="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" key={this.props.productData.name}>
                <button onClick={this.addToCart}>Click me!</button>
                <div className="row" >
                    <div onClick={addToCart} className="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 nopadding row-default" >
                        <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 nopadding">
                            <span className="table table-col ">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="cbxCheck2" className="jq_select_product" />
                                <label htmlFor="cbxCheck2" className="jq_select_product">{ this.props.productData.name }</label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs nopadding">
                            <span className="table table-col table-text-small">
                                { this.props.productData.label }
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 nopadding">
                            <span className="table table-col">
                                849,- (12 mnd)
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 nopadding">
                            <span className="table table-col table-text-small text-right">
                                <img id="imgShowMore" src="../../Images/arrow_purple_down.png" className="show-more _icon jq_expand_listview" /><label className="show-more _lbl jq_expand_listview">Vis mer</label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ProductDetails productData={this.props.productData} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
    addToCart: function (e) {
        alert("Hooooo!!!");
    },
});
```

Comment: Managed to solve this myself... Scripts need to be at the BOTTOM of the page... if not.. it's not working :(

Comment: Got answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996394/mvc-reactjs-button-onclick-event-not-get-fired/39018722#39018722

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After 1/2 a day of trial and error, i suddenly tried to put all the JSX file references at the bottom of the _Layout.cshtml page...

That solved it all actually...

Comment: have you considered putting the onClick handling function within the react-class? In that way, its bounded to that class only :)

Comment: Jepp :) That's what i have done now.. If you look closely.. you'll see i have two addToCart's... one "function addToCart()" and one addToCart: function() inside the react component :)

The first one was just for testing :)

Comment: Me too facing same issue, didn't get answer yet. Your solution is not working for me.

Comment: Got answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996394/mvc-reactjs-button-onclick-event-not-get-fired/39018722#39018722