# MVC-ReactJS button onclick event not get fired

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, reactjs, reactjs.net

I am creating simple stuff seeking for capturing button click event to some text or get some alert. ReactJS JSX code is pasted below:

```
var SearchBar = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {message: "test"};
},
test1: function(e) {
    alert('hi');
    this.setState({message: "New Message"});
},
render: function() {
    var self = this;
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={self.test1}>Change Message</button>
            {this.state.message}
        </div>
    );
},
```

});

I use above `SearchBar` component in MVC cshtml as:

```
@Html.React("SearchBar", new{ })
```

Button get rendered on html page, but unable to change `this.state.message` value on click event. **Where am I doing mistake?**

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that need to care about this issue

1. Add all **`jsx`** file uwins Script tag or using bundle in cshtml or in Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml file. e.g.
   @System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main")
2. Call **`@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()`** method after that.

Now Click event surely get work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you desire so:

`render: function() {
    return <div>
            <button onClick={this.test1}>Change Message</button>
            {this.state.message}
        </div>
  }`

Use `this` instead `self`

Comment: yes it would work for me too, but not working when using with MVC and reactJS.net